# How to set custom validity on a React component?

Tags: html, reactjs

I passed down a state flag from top component. If the flag is true the custom validity should be set otherwise the custom validity should be cleared. I am getting this error:

```
Unknown prop `setCustomValidity` on <input> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

However the problem is setCustomValidity is not recognised by React yet.

```
import React from "react";
import BaseField from "./BaseField";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const InputField = props => {
const { name, type, isMandatory, onChange, pattern, misMatchEmail } = props;

return (
    <BaseField {...props}>
    <input
        name={name}
        pattern={pattern}
        type={type}
        onChange={onChange}
        setCustomValidity={`${misMatchEmail} ? 'Confirm email does not match' : ''`}
        onSelect={e => e.preventDefault()}
        onCopy={e => e.preventDefault()}
        onPaste={e => e.preventDefault()}
        onCut={e => e.preventDefault()}
        required={isMandatory}
    />
    </BaseField>
);
};

InputField.propTypes = {
name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
isMandatory: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
misMatchEmail: PropTypes.bool,
pattern: PropTypes.string
};

export default InputField;
```

Can you please give me ideas how can I work around this?

Comment: first of all your ? inside es6 template literals(``)  is treated as string it is not working as if-else

use it like this 
setCustomValidity={ misMatchEmail ? 'Confirm email does not match' : '' }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one possible workaround you can use [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and in the corresponding handler set value of the attribute directly using pure javascript/jquery.
Something like this:

```
<input
   type="text"
   ref={(c) => { c.setAttribute("setCustomValidity", `${misMatchEmail} ? 'Confirm email does not match' : ''`); }} />
```

Comment: Do I have to change the functional component to class component for that purpose?

Comment: No - you should be fine. Have a look here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components

Comment: I'm getting this error Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: @NeginBasiri If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element. This is because a new instance of the function is created with each render, so React needs to clear the old ref and set up the new one. You can avoid this by defining the ref callback as a bound method on the class,

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to leverage `onChange` handler and set custom validity on `event.target` if possible. It seems to me as cleanest solution.

```
const Component = ({value, pattern, misMatchEmail, onChange}) => {
  
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.target.setCustomValidity(misMatchEmail ? 'Custom message' ? '');

    onChange(event);
  }
  
  return (
    <input value={value} pattern={pattern} onChange={handleInputChange} />
  )
}
```

And just for record. In case of `Refs` and functional components, we can use `useRef` hook as follows. Instead of `onChange` handler is also possible to leverage combination of `onInvalid` with `onKeyUp` handlers.

```
const Component = ({value, pattern, misMatchEmail, onChange}) => {
   const inputRef = React.useRef(null)

   const handleInputChange = (event) => {
     inputRef.current.setCustomValidity(misMatchEmail ? 'Custom message' ? '');

     onChange(event);
   }   
     
      
   return (
      <input ref={inputRef} value={value} pattern={pattern} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Amid's answer I have implemented simple function that can be easily use for input component (just remember to import react-dom library ;)) :

```
const setCustomValidityForInputText = (inputText, errorMessage) => {
      if (inputText instanceof InputText) {
        const htmlInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputText).querySelector('input');
        htmlInput.setAttribute('oninvalid', `this.setCustomValidity('${errorMessage}')`);
        htmlInput.setAttribute('oninput', "this.setCustomValidity('')");
      }
    };
```

and example of use somwehere in JSX (InputText is an extension of standard html input field) :

```
<InputText ref={(component) => setCustomValidityForInputText(component, 'Your error message goes here!')}/>
```